# CSS transition without affecting surrounding elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a grid of icons linking to separate web pages. I've achieved this as follows

I also want to create a small animation letting the user know that the items are clickable upon hovering. For this I've used the `transition` css property. However, when the images expand, the others around it are also adjusted to accomodate the expansion. How may I prevent the elements around the icons from moving when the transition happens?

```css
.icon-grid .col-sm-2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.icon-grid .col-sm-2 img:hover {
  width: 100%;
}

.icon-grid .col-sm-2 img {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  transition: width 2s;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="a.html">
        <img src="figures/fig.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="b.html">
        <img src="figures/fig.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="c.html">
        <img src="figures/fig.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="d.html">
        <img src="figures/fig.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="e.html">
        <img src="figures/fig.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <img src="figures/fig.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <img src="figures/fig.png>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <img src="figures/fig.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <img src="figures/fig.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <img src="figures/fig.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <img src="figures/fig.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using a special lirbary or framework? Otherwise both images `<img>` and linebreaks `<br>` are empty tags and have no slash as they also have no closing tag. There some fremworks that use a slash at the end but none that I know that would use `</ br>` which imo is in every case invalid html. Besides of that, using `<img><br><br>` is a bad use, you should use `img { display: block; margin-bottom: 2em; } ` isntead.

Comment: @tacoshy Updated code with your comments. I'm not using any special library, simply learning html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this method instead

```
.icon-grid .col-sm-2 img:hover {
  transform:scale(1.1);
}

.icon-grid .col-sm-2 img {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  transition:transform .25s ease;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```